# How to write python program that computes the value of n+nn+nnn+nnnn+... nn...n ntimes with a given number as the value of n

Tags: python

Write a program that computes the value of n+nn+nnn+nnnn+... nn...n ntimes with a given number as the value of n.
Ex :if n=3 , output = 3+33+333=369 and if n=1 output =1

My code is not working for input n=1
Can you please help

```
a = int(input("Input an integer : "))
n1 = int( "%s" % a )
n2 = int( "%s%s" % (a,a) )
n3 = int( "%s%s%s" % (a,a,a) )
print (n1+n2+n3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my code that'll work for this:

```
num = int(input('Enter in a value: '))
total = 0

for i in range(0, num):
    total += int(str(num) + i*str(num))
```

The way this works is that the user will first enter a number, of course. I keep a running total variable called 'total'. In my for-loop, I will loop from 0 to num. The reason why I chose 0 is because I don't want the first iteration to have more than one str(num). On the first iteration, i=0, effectively taking that  str(num) its multiplying out, leaving only one str(num) and then converting that to a int datatype by doing int(str(num)).

The second iteration, i=1, it'll look like this:

```
total += int(str(num) + 1*str(num))
```

which should be interpreted as (if the user entered 3 and is on their second iteration):

```
3 += int(str(3) + 2*str(3))
```

Total at this point would equal 36 and then on its third and final iteration, total will become 369. Hopefully that clarified my code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is always adding the repeated version of the string that you input 3 times. You need to use a loop.

```
n = input('n: ')
s = 0
for i in range(1, int(n) + 1):
    s += int(n * i) # n is a string, multiplying with int results in replication

print(s)
```

Comment: @Ankit could you provide some examples of why this code would be valid? Sample input and output will make the answer more clear. If code is not valid, please adjust and comment back here.

Comment: @NebiyouTen It doesn't. Note that n is a string.

Comment: @NebiyouTen n is a string so multiplying it with i is replicating it. It is computing n + nn + nnn + ...

Comment: @AnkitShaw alright, how about you consider adding this information into your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Since `3 + 33 + 333 = 369` can be re-interpreted as `3 x 3 + 2 x 30 + 1 x 300 = 369`, you can create such a mathematical function:

```
def f(n):
    return sum(10 ** i * (n - i) * n for i in range(n))
```

so that:

```
for n in range(6):
    print(f(n))
```

outputs:

```
0
1
24
369
4936
61725
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me correct your code

```
a = int(input("Input an integer : "))
p = 0
for i in range(1, a+1):
 p += int(str(a)*i)
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = int(input())
sum_ = 0
for i in range(1, number + 1):
    sum_ += int(str(number) * i)
print(sum_)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

#Take input

n=input()

#start writing your code here

ck=0

for i in range(1,int(n)+1):
ck=ck+int(i*n)

print(ck)

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
n=input()

#start writing your code form here
answer=0

for i in range(1,n+1):
    num=''
    for j in range(i):
        num=num+str(n)
    num=int(num)
    answer=answer+num

print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

For programmers that need an explanation:

```
def computeInt(nNum: int, nTimes: int) -> int:
    result = 0
    # how many times to multiple
    for i in range(0, nTimes):
        # result adding in each loop the iterator = 5 + n * str(5)
        # first is 5, second is 55, third is 555 the result is adding all of that as integer
        result += int(str(nNum) + i * str(nNum))
    return result


print(computeInt(5, 3))
```